# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'start_time'

Tags: java

i get this error...

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'start_time'

please help me solve this..

controller.java

```
package com.rsmagsys.rs.registration.doctorSchedule;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.rsmagsys.rs.Utility.JsonResponse;
import com.rsmagsys.rs.registration.model.StaffScheduleForm;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Controller
public class DoctorScheduleController {

@Autowired
private DAODoctorScheduleForm dao;

@RequestMapping(value = "registration/doctor-schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registerInPatient(Locale locale, Model model) {
    return "registration/doctorSchedule/doctorScheduleListing";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "registration/doctor-schedule/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse save(Model model, StaffScheduleForm ssf) {
    JsonResponse jr = new JsonResponse();
    try {
        StaffScheduleForm staffSchedule = dao.saveDataDoctorSchedule (ssf);
        jr.setStatus("success");
        jr.setResult(staffSchedule);
    } catch (RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        jr.setStatus("error");
    }
    return jr;
}
}
```

DAOForm.java

```
package com.rsmagsys.rs.registration.doctorSchedule;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.jfree.util.Log;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.rsmagsys.rs.registration.model.StaffScheduleForm;
import com.rsmagsys.rs.registration.outpatient.DAORegOutPatientForm;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Repository
public class DAODoctorScheduleForm {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public StaffScheduleForm saveDataDoctorSchedule(StaffScheduleForm ssf){

    Date start_time = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "SELECT to_char(nextval('rsmagsys.seq_start'))",Date.class);
    Date end_time = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "SELECT to_char(nextval('rsmagsys.seq_end'))",Date.class);

    log.info("start_time" + start_time);
    log.info("end_time" + end_time);


    ssf.setStart_time(start_time);
    ssf.setEnd_time(end_time);

    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "insert into rsmagsys.staff_schedule(start_time, end_time)  values(?,?)",
            ssf.getStart_time(), ssf.getEnd_time()
    );




    return ssf;
}

}
```

javascript.jsp

```
$.ajax({url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registration/out-patient/save',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                id_no : id_no,
                name : name,
                dob : dob,
                visit_date_time : visit_date_time
            },
            success : function(data) {
                toastr.success("Record save successfully!");

                var patient_id = data.result.patient_id;
                var mrn_no = data.result.mrn_no;
                var episode_id = data.result.episode_id;
                var que_no = data.result.que_no;
                var name_upper = data.result.name;

                console.log(name_upper);
                console.log(patient_id);
                console.log(mrn_no);
                console.log(episode_id);
                console.log(que_no);

                document.getElementById("patient_name").value = name_upper;
                document.getElementById("patient_id").value = patient_id;
                document.getElementById("mrn_no").value = mrn_no;
                document.getElementById("episode_id").value = episode_id;
                document.getElementById("que_no").value = que_no;
            },
            failure : function(data) {
                toastr
                        .error("There's an error while saving your record.");
            }
        });
```

html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="doctorSchedulePopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:white;">Create Doctor Schedule</h4>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label-popup">Department</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="department">
                                <option>Please Select</option>
                            </select>
                            <span id="department_error" class="error" style="display: none">*Department Is Required</span>
                        </div>

                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label-popup">Date Start</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </span> 
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="2015-11-01" id="date_start" onSelect="">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label-popup">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">Doctor Name</a>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctor_name">
                        <span id="doctor_name_error" class="error" style="display: none">*Doctor Name Is Required</span>
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label-popup">Date End</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </span> 
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="2015-11-01" id="date_end" onSelect="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label-popup"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-left">Time Start/End</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_time"/> 
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                <span id="start_time_error" class="error" style="display: none">*Time Start Is Required</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end_time"/> 
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                hh:mm
                                <span id="end_time_error" class="error" style="display: none">*Time End Is Required</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label-popup">
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-left">New Schedule Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </span> 
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="2015-11-01" id="schedule_date" onSelect="">
                                <span id="schedule_date_error" class="error" style="display: none">*Schedule Date Is Required</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </form>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pullleft">Add</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pullleft">Remove</button>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"  onclick="save()">Create Schedule</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Copy from Selected Date</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#5F9EA0;color:white;">Selected records pending
                    creation..</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="success">
                                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Staff ID</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Doctor Name</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Time Start</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Time End</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">  <input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox" value=""></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are converting to String in  `SELECT to_char`

Comment: It would be helpful to add more details, like complete stack trace or simply class and line number on which your are getting error, instead of adding all the related files.

Answer (score 0):

In the first 2 lines of method `saveDataDoctorSchedule` from class `DAOForm.java` you have query that converts the value for given column to varchar2 using `to_char()` but you are assigning its value to `Date` object.

Read more about to_char(): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

> TO_CHAR (datetime) converts a datetime or interval value of DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE datatype to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype